# generic image not removing

Tags: grub2, kernel, lubuntu

```
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states
```

This error comes up while upgrading. I also tried to delete the package but not removing.

Comment: How do you upgrade? We need the exact commands your are running and their output. What package are you trying to remove? What version of Ubuntu do you have? Please [edit] your question and add all this info. You can consult [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to properly format your question.

Comment: What you've provided is the end-summary relating to errors further up the report you provided the summary snippet from. All we can currently tell you is to read the full report (we can only see what you provide us, we also don't know your release details etc as BeastOfCaerbannog already stated)